# Table with borders problem

Tags: tables

I have a problem with borders in multirow. I would really appraciate someones help.

My code:

```
\begin{tabular}{ | m{2cm} | m{3.2cm}|| m{2cm}| m{3.2cm}|} 
\hline
Linia & Energia teor. [eV] & Linia & Energia teor. [eV] \\
\hline
\hline
Cr~$K_{\alpha 1}$  & 5~405.5384(71) & \multirow{2}{2cm}{Cr~$K_{\alpha}$} &  \multirow{2}{3.2cm}{5405.5384(71)} \\ 
Cr~$K_{\alpha 2}$ & 5~413.88(42)    \\
\hline
Cr~$K_{\beta 1}$ & 5~940.74(92) & \multirow{2}{2cm}{Cr~$K_{\beta}$} & \multirow{2}{3.2cm}{5414.8045(71)} \\
Cr~$K_{\beta1}$ & 5~947.10(100) \\
\hline
Fe~$K_{\alpha 1}$  &  6 391.0264(99)  & \multirow{2}{*}{Fe~$K_{\alpha}$} & \multirow{2}{*}{6391.0264(99)}   \\
Fe~$K_{\alpha 2}$& 6~403.13(43)\\
\hline
Fe~$K_{\beta 1}$ & 77~053.23(100)& \multirow{2}{2cm}{Fe~$K_{\beta}$} &  \multirow{2}{3.2cm}{6404.0062(99)}\\
Fe~$K_{\beta 2}$ & 7~059.9(11)\\
\hline
Ni~$K_{\alpha 1}$  & 7 461.0343(45) & \multirow{2}{2cm}{Ni~$K_{\alpha}$} &  multirow{2}{3.2cm}{7461.0343(45)}\\
Ni~$K_{\alpha 2}$& 7~477.72(44) \\
\hline
Ni~$K_{\beta 1}$  & 8~262.4(11)  & \multirow{2}{2cm}{Ni~$K_{\beta}$} & \multirow{2}{3.2cm}{7478.2521(45)}\\
Ni~$K_{\beta 2}$ & 8~267.6(11)\\
\hline 
\end{tabular}
```

[image: my_lable]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE :) Please provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) (that compiles without errors) and state your question or desired output.

Answer (score 2):

With the package `tabularray`, it's the first time i use. Many example of this site.

[image]

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tabularray}
    \begin{document}

    \begin{tblr}{
            vlines,
            colspec = {X[l,wd=2cm] X[l,wd=3.2cm] | X[l,wd=2cm] X[l,wd=3.2cm]},
        }
        \hline
    Linia             & Energia teor. [eV] & Linia                             & Energia teor. [eV]              \\
        \hline
        \hline
        Cr~$K_{\alpha 1}$ & 5~405.5384(71)     & \SetCell[r=2]{m}{Cr~$K_{\alpha}$} & \SetCell[r=2]{m}{5405.5384(71)} \\
        Cr~$K_{\alpha 2}$ & 5~413.88(42)     &&\\
        \hline
    \end{tblr}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without a [minimum working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that), I had to guess what packages you used.

You simply need to add the "empty" cells in the lines after multirow

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ | m{2cm} | m{3.2cm}|| m{2cm}| m{3.2cm}|} 
\hline
Linia & Energia teor. [eV] & Linia & Energia teor. [eV] \\
\hline
\hline
Cr~$K_{\alpha 1}$  & 5~405.5384(71) & \multirow{2}{2cm}{Cr~$K_{\alpha}$} &  \multirow{2}{3.2cm}{5405.5384(71)} \\ 
Cr~$K_{\alpha 2}$ & 5~413.88(42) & & \\
\hline
Cr~$K_{\beta 1}$ & 5~940.74(92) & \multirow{2}{2cm}{Cr~$K_{\beta}$} & \multirow{2}{3.2cm}{5414.8045(71)} \\
Cr~$K_{\beta1}$ & 5~947.10(100) & &\\
\hline
Fe~$K_{\alpha 1}$  &  6 391.0264(99)  & \multirow{2}{*}{Fe~$K_{\alpha}$} & \multirow{2}{*}{6391.0264(99)}   \\
Fe~$K_{\alpha 2}$& 6~403.13(43) & &\\
\hline
Fe~$K_{\beta 1}$ & 77~053.23(100)& \multirow{2}{2cm}{Fe~$K_{\beta}$} &  \multirow{2}{3.2cm}{6404.0062(99)}\\
Fe~$K_{\beta 2}$ & 7~059.9(11) & &\\
\hline
Ni~$K_{\alpha 1}$  & 7 461.0343(45) & \multirow{2}{2cm}{Ni~$K_{\alpha}$} &  \multirow{2}{3.2cm}{7461.0343(45)}\\
Ni~$K_{\alpha 2}$& 7~477.72(44) & & \\
\hline
Ni~$K_{\beta 1}$  & 8~262.4(11)  & \multirow{2}{2cm}{Ni~$K_{\beta}$} & \multirow{2}{3.2cm}{7478.2521(45)}\\
Ni~$K_{\beta 2}$ & 8~267.6(11) & &\\
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

In a LaTeX table, if you don't write the delimiter, the cell won't be drawn. It consider you want the line to end at this cell, and don't need the rest of the line.

hope it helps